# how open an intent using webview in android?

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, webview

I am using [Vudriod](https://code.google.com/p/vudroid/) to show pdf on my own app. If i run this code I can see the pdf:

> final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
>
> String uriString = uri.toString();
>
> String extension = uriString.substring(uriString.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
>
> intent.setClass(this, extensionToActivity.get(extension));
>
> startActivity(intent);

But i need to open pdf using webview because i have html interactions and want to overload html on top the pdf. is it possible to show the intent inside webview instead of using startactivity?

if it is not possible, is it possible to open webview upon activity but in transparent background. Then call zoomin and scrolling event of intent when webview got these events?

I am very new in android, please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
String googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url="; 
mWebView.loadUrl(googleDocs + url);
```

Comment: I dont want to connect to internet and show my PDF, this is why I use Vudriod. But i need to have interaction upon pdfviewer using webview. This answer is wrong

Comment: hello there is no bultin pdfviewer provide by the google all third party pdf viewer developed by outher company